# класс StringBuffer и StringBuilder

Tags: java

В чем разница между классами StringBuffer и StringBuilder в языке Java?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`StringBuffer` давно устарел и не рекомендуется к применению. О чём можно найти упоминания в "Effective Java" Джошуа Блоха, "Java Concurrency in Practice" Брайана Гетца и многих других учебниках. Его основное отличие от `StringBuilder` в том, что вызов метода `append` синхронизирован. В однопоточной среде это приводит к бесполезному замедлению программы. А в многопоточной бесполезно, так как смысл имеет только совместная синхронизация всех вызовов `append`, а не каждого по отдельности.

Answer (score 3):

StringBuffer синхронизирован, а StringBuilder - нет.

Соответственно StringBuilder работает быстрее и его следует применять там, где синхронизация (`synchronized`) не нужна.

Answer (score 3):

Эти классы похожи, практически двойники, они имеют одинаковые конструкторы, одни и те же методы, которые одинаково используются. Единственное их различие состоит в том, что класс StringBuffer синхронизированный и потокобезопасный. То есть класс StringBuffer удобнее использовать в многопоточных приложениях, где объект данного класса может меняться в различных потоках. Если же речь о многопоточных приложениях не идет, то лучше использовать класс StringBuilder, который не потокобезопасный, но при этом работает быстрее, чем StringBuffer в однопоточных приложениях.