# Русские символы для FileInputStream

Tags: java

у меня есть интерфейс а в нем метод

```
void setSource (FileInputStream fis) throws IOException;
```

я реализовал этот метод:

```
@Override
public void setSource(FileInputStream fis) throws IOException {
    StringBuffer stringBuffer = new StringBuffer();
    int i = -1;
    while ((i = fis.read()) != -1) {
        stringBuffer.append((char)i);
    }
    this.text = stringBuffer.toString();
}
```

И эта реализация работает только с латинскими символами, а кириллица отображается криво.
Как это исправить?

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте указать кодировку.

```
@Override
public void setSource(FileInputStream fis) throws IOException {
    UnicodeReader ur = new UnicodeReader(fis, "CP1251");
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(ur);
    final StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

    String line;
    while ((line = br.readLine()) != null)
        sb.append(line);

    this.text = sb.toString();
}
```

Comment: Похоже это не очень помогло, incompatible types: java.io.FileInputStream cannot be converted to com.sun.tools.javac.parser.ScannerFactory

Answer (score 1):

Необходимо указать кодировку файла

```
@Override
public void setSource(FileInputStream fis) throws IOException {
    StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
    try (InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(fis, StandardCharsets.UTF_8)) {
        int i = -1;
        while ((i = fis.read()) != -1) {
            stringBuilder.append((char)i);
        }
    }
    this.text = stringBuilder.toString();
}
```

И не используйте `StringBuffer`, он [медленный и устаревший](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/806464/204271).

Comment: Спасибо за совет о StringBuilder, но Ваша реализация тоже к сожалению не не помогла поменять кодировку, но натолкнула на идею

Answer (score 0):

Спасибо за помощь, но вот что я придумал:

```
@Override
    public void setSource(FileInputStream fis) throws IOException {
        StringBuilder stringBuffer = new StringBuilder();
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fis, "UTF8"));
        String str;
        while ((str = in.readLine()) != null) {
            stringBuffer.append(str);
        }
        this.text = stringBuffer.toString();
        in.close();
    }
```

Comment: Если вы обернёте в try/catch свой код, то использование in.close() не обязательно. Ресурс автоматически освободиться сам. Основной вашей проблемой было - незнание кодировки входного потока. Все ответы верные.